# Adding items to a sorted observablecollection

Tags: c#, sorting, observablecollection, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a list of items that need to be sorted by date, So what I'm doing is the following (I'm binding an `ItemsControl` to `Pushes`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Push> Pushes
        {
            get { return Settings.PushCol; }
            set { Settings.PushCol = value; OnPropertyChanged("Pushes"); }
        }


    Pushes = new ObservableCollection<Push>(
        Settings.PushCol
            .Where(push => push.Active == true)
            .OrderByDescending(push => push.Created)
    );
```

The problem here is if I were to add to `Pushes`, I would have to resort my `Pushes` using the code above, the issue this causes is that if I have a large collection it will freeze the UI until the collection has been updated.

I'm trying to find a better way to do this, can anyone advise me on what would be the best practice here?

Comment: Do this in another thread. when the sorting is done call `Dispatcher` to assign to `pushes` in UI Thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, don't us `set`ters for your lists. That way, you can control how items are added to your list.

There are ways to sort items for an ObservableCollection via an `CollectionViewSource`. You can read about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542.aspx).

Another solution would be to expose your list as an `IEnumerable<Push>`

```
public IEnumerable<Push> Pushes // no Add method on IEnumerable
{
    get { return Settings.PushCol; }
}
```

Then implement an `Add` method in your class, which controls how items are added.

```
public void Add(Push p){
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < Settings.PushCol.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Settings.PushCol[i].Created > p.Created)
            break;
    }
    Settings.PushCol.Insert(i, p);
}
```

Comment: OK thanks for that, so in my // do sorting here what would I place?

Comment: Now that I think of it, maybe it would be better to expose the property as `IEnumerable` and use an `Add(Push p)` method in your class. That way you can use `Insert` on the collection instead. Is it possible for you to change the property type?

Comment: Well it's still very early in development so I can change nearly everything if I want. How would `IEnumerable` merge in with all this?

Comment: OK here's another thing I may have missed out. I'm using JSON.NET and it's ToObject() method to populate the ObservableCollection at once, my thought on that is that it's not hitting the add method. Since I only care about the sorting on the UI I was thinking could I implement some sort of converter on my binding that will handle this?

Comment: Sure, that might work. Or use a CollectionViewSource. Unfortunately I am not familiar with JSON parsing and how that adds to a collection. You might want to provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates your current solution.

Comment: Well the JSON parsing doesn't matter, all I'm doing is creating an ObservableCollection of the JSON Object and calling `Settings.PushCol = JSONDATA;` I just need to handle the sorting on the UI.

Comment: The new CollectionViewSource can't sort

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sorted add for observable collection using custom comparer
    /// </summary>
    public static void AddSorted<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, T item, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        var sortableList = new List<T>(collection);
        int index = sortableList.BinarySearch(item, comparer);
        if (index < 0)
            index = ~index;
        collection.Insert(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).